# Mudança tipo campo MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber se é possível alterar o tipo de dados de uma coluna em Mysql. Por exemplo: tenho uma tabela `USUARIO` com a coluna `SITUACAO`, em `varchar` e preciso alterar para `bit`. Pensei em fazer algo como:

```
UPDATE usuario SET situacao=1 WHERE situacao='ativo';
UPDATE usuario SET situacao=0 WHERE situacao='inativo';
```

depois

```
ALTER TABLE usuario CHANGE situacao situacao BIT;
```

Isso vai funcionar ? Alguém sabe um jeito melhor pra fazer isso ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sim, isso vai funcionar.**

Na minha opinião, não existe motivo para procurar outra maneira de fazer se desta forma funciona perfeitamente.

Como alternativa você poderia criar outra coluna para salvar o novo valor (`BIT`) e depois limpar a coluna atual, trocar o tipo dela, passar os valores pra ela e depois excluir a segunda coluna, mas como podes ver, isso é muito trabalhoso pra chegar exatamente no mesmo resultado. Dependendo do caso, isso pode ser necessário, só você vai saber.

Aqui vai um exemplo.

```
ALTER TABLE USUARIO ADD SITUACAO_BACKUP BIT NOT NULL;
UPDATE USUARIO SET SITUACAO_BACKUP = 0 WHERE SITUACAO = 'inativo';
UPDATE USUARIO SET SITUACAO_BACKUP = 1 WHERE SITUACAO = 'ativo';
UPDATE USUARIO SET SITUACAO = NULL;

ALTER TABLE USUARIO CHANGE COLUMN SITUACAO SITUACAO BIT;
UPDATE USUARIO SET SITUACAO = SITUACAO_BACKUP;

ALTER TABLE USUARIO DROP COLUMN SITUACAO_BACKUP;
```

<sup>**[Código no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/blob/master/SQL/MySQL/91342/backup-in-table.sql)**</sup>

Comment: Pois é, posso fazer um backup da coluna na própria tabela. Obrigada pela dica !!!

Answer (score 6):

Sim, essa instrução vai funcionar e vai manter os valores convertidos, no caso 1 para ativo e 0 para inativo.

Outra alernativa é criar uma coluna nova e depois realizar os updates um a um.

```
ALTER TABLE usuario MODIFY situacao BIT;
```

Comment: Qual a diferença entre o MODIFY e o CHANGE ?

Comment: Com `MODIFY` vc não consegue mudar o nome da coluna, apenas os atributos como tamanho tipo nesse sentido. Com `CHANGE` vc pode alterar o tipo, tamanho e nome, veja que aparece duas vezes o nome do campo aqui `CHANGE situacao situacao BIT` ou seja ele está sendo renomeado e tipo também será trocado. @Donnathegirl

Comment: Mais negócio usar o MODIFY então XD
Obrigada @rray !!!

Comment: @Donnathegirl, nesse caso sim, a alteração é só no tipo e não no nome.

Answer (score 4):

Crie uma tabela de apoio e guarde uma cópia do dados atuais que pode ser somente a chave primária e o campo situação. Porque, se acontecer algum incoveniente tu tem um backup dos dados atuais.

Coloque os dados assim com aspas igual no código abaixo, faltou esse detalhe.

```
UPDATE usuario SET situacao='1' WHERE situacao='ativo';
```

Faça o processo de atualização e se tu receber nenhum erro prossiga com o outro código de alteração de tipo.

```
ALTER TABLE usuario CHANGE COLUMN situacao situacao BIT;
```

Nunca faça nada sem ter um backup !!!

Comment: Poxa, não tinha pensado em um backup... Obrigada!!!

Comment: É sempre bom ter backup, versionamentos e outras formas pra ter como voltar ao estado anterior ... @Donnathegirl espero ter ajudado!